# Debug assertion failed, Expression: (unsigned)(c + 1) <=256

Tags: c, runtime-error

What I am trying to do:
Make a program that opens a file and read the content (mostly characters)
Example on what it should do:

The file contains "ABA", It should print: Letter A Count 2 || Letter B Count 1
but I am getting this error when I start debugging https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqa5T.jpg

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct arr
{
     char letter;
     int count;
};

void main ()
{
   arr s[7];
   char letter;
   FILE *fp;
 fp=fopen("D:\\data.txt","r");
 if(fp==NULL)
{
    printf("Error File Not Found\n");
    getch();
    exit(1);
}
 while(fscanf(fp,"%ch",&letter)!=EOF)
 {
     for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
     {
     if(!isalpha(s[i].letter))
     {
         s[i].letter=letter;
         s[i].count=1;
         break;
     }
     else if(s[i].letter == letter)
         s[i].count++;
     break;
     }
 }
    for(int h=0;h<7;h++)
    printf("Letter: %c Count: %d ||",s[h].letter,s[h].count);
 getch();
}
```

Where am i wrong exactly ?

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to `s[i].letter` before your if check.  You need to be validating `letter`

Comment: According to the man pages `isalpha` requires a valid `unsigned char` or `EOF`

Comment: changed the `char letter` in the struct to `unsigned char` and it works now but the output isn't correct, it should print Letter A count 2 || Letter B Count 1.
But instead, it only prints Letter A Count 2 and not the B (ignoring the rest of the outputs)

Comment: Look @ your loop the second time through.  If `!isalpha(s[0]//"A")`...`else if (s[0]//'A' == 'B')` neither of these will pass, so "B" won't get counted.  I told you earlier, you have to check against `letter`.

Comment: there were braces I forgot to put inside `else if` condition, now it works. Thanks

Comment: `arr s[7];` --> `struct arr s[7] = {{0}};`

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem might be -**

function **isalpha()** is being called with an integer whose value is not a single byte i.e. 0-255.

Comment: So my only choice is to change `if(!isalpha(s[i].letter))` to 


`if(!(s[i].letter>='A' && s[i].letter<='Z'))`?